# How can I detect regular expressions in an Outlook-Mail subjectline and automatically hyperlinking it?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I'm trying to check the subject line to a match with my regex. If it hits I would like to automaticly hyperlink the matches, so my browser opens a website after clicking a link.

Another problem is that you can't use HTML code in a subject line, so I can manipulate the html code of the mail body but I can't use "mailItem.subject.HTMLBody" to manipulate the subject line.

I found some solutions for web-add-ins but I'm using VSTO-Add-In.

I thought maybe it exists a kind of overlay or something like that. Or for example like Word is underlining wrong written words, so you can deal with that word by right click.

I hope someone can help me.

sincerely Florian

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.  Can you post what you've already tried, do you have any relevant code at all?

Comment: Hyperlink then where? As far as I’m aware the subject line is plain text, so any markup wouldn’t be interpreted anyway.